# Android's weird behavior with general sibling selector when adding class dynamically

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, selector

While I was writing some html&javascript codes, I've found a weird behavior with my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy 3, 4.1.2).

What I tried to achieve was to show sibling tr elements of first tr element by giving a class name to it dynamically. The class has general sibling selector to give the sibling TRs "display:table-row"  which are originally "display:none"

Below I briefly wrote some code similar to what I'm having problem with.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5yXR/

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="a"><td>test a</td></tr>
    <tr class="b"><td>test b</td></tr>
    <tr class="c"><td>test c</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<style>
.a{display:table-row;}
.b{display:none;}
.c{display:none;}
.a.active~tr{display:table-row}
</style>

<script>
$('.a').click(function(){ $(this).addClass('active') })
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but I ran into the same issue on an android Samsung tab3 tablet, and found a (lame) fix.
Basically, my rows that were hidden/shown from the general sibling selector were selected by their class name, instead of their element name. I then simply removed/added the class on the rows...which for whatever reason updates the rows accordingly. I tried forcing a reflow, but that was a no go. In the end, i'm not sure what the issue is, but this worked, despite being a bad fix in my opinion as this could be a costly operation on a mobile device with a lots of rows to update...

Anyway, if I take your example, the fix would be as follow: 
( or as a jsfiffle: http://jsfiddle.net/kTWS2/ )

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="a"><td>test a</td></tr>
    <tr class="b"><td>test b</td></tr>
    <tr class="b"><td>test c</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<style>
    .a{display:table-row;}
    .b{display:none;}
    .a.active~.b{display:table-row}
</style>

<script>
    $('.a').click(function(){
        $(this)
            .toggleClass('active')
            .parent()
            .find('.b')
            .removeClass('b')
            .addClass('b');
    });
</script>
```